# How to write a Utilily function which returns all elements in an array after 2 elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a utility which fetches all elements of an array after 2 elements

I have tried it this way but i am getting undefined

```
// ARRAYS
var arr = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];

var valuefromutility = getcommasperatedvalue(arr);
console.log(valuefromutility);

function getcommasperatedvalue(arr)
{
var arrayafter3elemnts = '';
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
        if (i > 2)
        {
                if (i === arr.length - 1)
                {
                        arrayafter3elemnts += arr[i];
                }
                else
                {
                        arrayafter3elemnts += arr[i] + ',';
                }
        }
}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/336/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fetch all elements after the first 2 elements, use [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```js
function getcommasperatedvalue(arr) {
    return arr.slice(2).join(',');
}

var arr = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];
console.log(getcommasperatedvalue(arr));
```

Comment: simple and efficient .

Comment: If you dont mind how to handle the above in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/340/ (array format changed )

Comment: @UnKnown - handle how, it works fine with an array of objects, but the string value of an object is `[object, Object]` so you probably don't want to stringify it

Comment: really sorry i didn't get what you mean

Comment: There's a difference between strings and objects. Your question posts code that returns a string, joined by a comma, when you suddenly change the input from strings to objects, the entire premise of the question changes, and now you can no longer return a string joined by a comma, you have to return an array of objects instead.

Answer (score 1):

Why just don't start the loop with index 2?

`for (var i = 2; i < arr.length; i++)`

Answer (score 1):

In js array `slice` make this easy with any index

```
// ARRAYS
var arr = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];

var valuefromutility = getcommasperatedvalue(arr,2);
console.log(valuefromutility);

function getcommasperatedvalue(arr,index)
{
     return arr.slice(index).join(',');
}
```